# zClip - ZeroClipboard.swf deleted - Need new file

Tags: zeroclipboard, zclip

I'm using [zClip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) on my website to copy several things in textboxes, I got everything working just fine but now, without changing anything, it stopped working.

The reason is that the host of the file [ZeroClipboard.swf](http://zeroclipboard.googlecode.com/svn-history/r10/trunk/ZeroClipboard.swf) have deleted the file or for some reason made inaccessible.

I have an other version(?) of the ZeroClipboard.swf on my computer from another script and I tried replacing the deleted link with a new link of the other version(?) I found on my computer.
But it doesn't work, the flash movie loads but I can't click my button and copy the content.
When I'm using the old link that doesn't work anymore it says "Movie hasn't loaded yet". It can't load because the file is inaccessible.

So because with the new link the movie loads but doesn't work, I'm sure it's another version not compatible with my script.

**Now to my question:**
Do any of you have the version of ZeroClipboard.swf that was hosted on the SteamDev.com site?
If, could you possibly upload it somewhere for me to download, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: God I love SO. I had the same problem on the same site for the same reason and lo and behold, here's a shrinkwrapped solution. Badass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was searching for `ZeroClipboard.swf` today, and I got the same problem.

Looking around, I found a tutorial about it [here](http://davidwalsh.name/clipboard). You can see there's a hosted version of `ZeroClipboard.swf`, here is the url:

http://davidwalsh.name/demo/ZeroClipboard.swf

I tried this version and it works like a charm. Now, I highly recommend you to host your proper version of this file, to avoid this kind of problem later.

Comment: Is this file a blank page? Does it do something while it's a blank page?

Comment: It's not a "blank page", you've got a Flash element (filling the page). Via the `setText()` function, this element will put everything you provide in your clipboard. See it : **Right click > Flash Player**.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the official site and then open the source code and copy swf path from there :)

here it is http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf

Answer (score 1):

It didn't load because it was blocked due to XSS vulnerability http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2013/Mar/207
Now you can get a safe version from https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard

Answer (score 0):

Get ZeroClipboard.swf file  from following link:

https://github.com/paulirish/css3please/blob/master/ZeroClipboard.swf

Answer (score 0):

The answer above didn't work for me but I looked at zClip's source and found the url for the .swf they are using; http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf